# Remove "View report" link on a dashboard - Lightning

Tags: lightning, dashboard

Is there a way, we can remove the "View Report" link on a dashboard for some profiles? Please note that I still need to see the dashboard results but just not the link to View drill down of the report.

[image]

Comment: IDEA - https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=0873A000000CUPFQA4.
Its an IDEA in Salesforce.